# Display specific custom product attributes on single product pages in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I found the [following code](https://isabelcastillo.com/woocommerce-product-attributes-functions) to display all custom attributes on a product detail page (with a specific bar-style design that I need). The code works like a charm and I have the proper CSS to display horizontal bars of my custom attributes.

> Problem I have is that I only want to display specific named
>   attributes and don't know how to change the loop to do that...

```
function isa_woocommerce_all_pa(){

global $product;
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();

if ( ! $attributes ) {
    return;
}

$out = '<ul class="taste-attributes">';

foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {


    // skip variations
    if ( $attribute->get_variation() ) {
    continue;
    }
    $name = $attribute->get_name();
    if ( $attribute->is_taxonomy() ) {

        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), $name, 'all' );
        // get the taxonomy
        $tax = $terms[0]->taxonomy;
        // get the tax object
        $tax_object = get_taxonomy($tax);
        // get tax label
        if ( isset ( $tax_object->labels->singular_name ) ) {
            $tax_label = $tax_object->labels->singular_name;
        } elseif ( isset( $tax_object->label ) ) {
            $tax_label = $tax_object->label;
            // Trim label prefix since WC 3.0
            if ( 0 === strpos( $tax_label, 'Product ' ) ) {
               $tax_label = substr( $tax_label, 8 );
            }                
        }


        $out .= '<li class="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '">';
        $out .= '<p class="attribute-label">' . esc_html( $tax_label ) . ': </p> ';
        $tax_terms = array();
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $single_term = esc_html( $term->name );
            // Insert extra code here if you want to show terms as links.
            array_push( $tax_terms, $single_term );
        }
        $out .= '<span class="attribute-value">' . implode(', ', $tax_terms) . '</span><progress value="' . implode(', ', $tax_terms) .
        '" max="10"><div class="progress-bar"><span style="width:'
        . implode(', ', $tax_terms) . '0%">'
        . implode(', ', $tax_terms) . '</span></div></progress></li>';


        } else {
            $value_string = implode( ', ', $attribute->get_options() );
            $out .= '<li class="' . sanitize_title($name) . ' ' . sanitize_title( $value_string ) . '">';
            $out .= '<p class="attribute-label">' . $name . ': </p> ';
            $out .= '<progress value="' . esc_html( $value_string ) . '" max="10"></progress></li>';
        }
    }

    $out .= '</ul>';

    echo $out;
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'isa_woocommerce_all_pa', 20);
```

Comment: the slug for one of the three attributes (I need to list with the above design) is
"fyllighet"

Comment: I got the correct way to make it work as you want… try it, and let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the following code you will define first the desired product attributes slugs in an array, that will get displayed in single product pages:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_some_product_attributes', 25 );
function display_some_product_attributes(){
    // HERE define the desired product attributes to be displayed
    $defined_attributes = array('fyllighet', 'carrier', 'billing-e-number');

    global $product;
    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();

    if ( ! $attributes ) {
        return;
    }

    $out = '<ul class="taste-attributes">';

    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {

        // Get the product attribute slug from the taxonomy
        $attribute_slug = str_replace( 'pa_', '', $attribute->get_name() );

        // skip all non desired product attributes
        if ( ! in_array($attribute_slug, $defined_attributes) ) {
            continue;
        }

        // skip variations
        if ( $attribute->get_variation() ) {
            continue;
        }

        $name = $attribute->get_name();

        if ( $attribute->is_taxonomy() ) {

            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), $name, 'all' );
            // get the taxonomy
            $tax = $terms[0]->taxonomy;
            // get the tax object
            $tax_object = get_taxonomy($tax);
            // get tax label
            if ( isset ( $tax_object->labels->singular_name ) ) {
                $tax_label = $tax_object->labels->singular_name;
            } elseif ( isset( $tax_object->label ) ) {
                $tax_label = $tax_object->label;
                // Trim label prefix since WC 3.0
                if ( 0 === strpos( $tax_label, 'Product ' ) ) {
                   $tax_label = substr( $tax_label, 8 );
                }                
            }

            $out .= '<li class="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '">';
            $out .= '<p class="attribute-label">' . esc_html( $tax_label ) . ': </p> ';
            $tax_terms = array();

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $single_term = esc_html( $term->name );
                // Insert extra code here if you want to show terms as links.
                array_push( $tax_terms, $single_term );
            }

            $out .= '<span class="attribute-value">' . implode(', ', $tax_terms) . '</span><progress value="' . implode(', ', $tax_terms) .
            '" max="10"><div class="progress-bar"><span style="width:'
            . implode(', ', $tax_terms) . '0%">'
            . implode(', ', $tax_terms) . '</span></div></progress></li>';

        } else {
            $value_string = implode( ', ', $attribute->get_options() );
            $out .= '<li class="' . sanitize_title($name) . ' ' . sanitize_title( $value_string ) . '">';
            $out .= '<p class="attribute-label">' . $name . ': </p> ';
            $out .= '<progress value="' . esc_html( $value_string ) . '" max="10"></progress></li>';
        }
    }

    $out .= '</ul>';

    echo $out;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: And how do you call it in the single page product so it can be displayed @LoicTheAztec

Comment: @GeofreyMartin The hook `woocommerce_single_product_summary` allows to make the display of it in single product pages… Now on some themes it will not work, because they are making changes to WooCommerce templates or they are using blocks (not templates)…

Comment: Oooh ok, and what if i want to put value of that attribute on specific area of Single Product Page.

Comment: So check [WooCommerce Visual Hook Guide: Single Product Page](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/) where you will see all available hooks for single product pages…

Comment: Thanks a lot, the link is very helpfully.