# Display and render specific custom product attributes to images on single product pages in Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a solution to have specific product attributes on a single product page. Based on [Display specific custom product attributes on single product pages in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936657/display-specific-custom-product-attributes-on-single-product-pages-in-woocommerc/51944539#51944539) answer code, I made some little changes here below
to display the selected attribute on single product pages:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_some_product_attributes', 25 );
    function display_some_product_attributes(){
        // HERE define the desired product attributes to be displayed
        $defined_attributes = array('attributeB', 'attributeC', 'attributeD');
    
        global $product;
        $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
        
        echo '<div style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: 500; margin-bottom: 5px; text-transform: uppercase;"><span>Sensorik</span></div>';
        
        if ( ! $attributes ) {
            return;
        }
    
        $out = '<ul class="taste-attributes">';
    
        foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
    
            // Get the product attribute slug from the taxonomy
            $attribute_slug = str_replace( 'pa_', '', $attribute->get_name() );
    
            // skip all non desired product attributes
            if ( ! in_array($attribute_slug, $defined_attributes) ) {
                continue;
            }
    
            // skip variations
            if ( $attribute->get_variation() ) {
                continue;
            }
    
            $name = $attribute->get_name();
    
            if ( $attribute->is_taxonomy() ) {
    
                $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), $name, 'all' );
                // get the taxonomy
                $tax = $terms[0]->taxonomy;
                // get the tax object
                $tax_object = get_taxonomy($tax);
                // get tax label
                if ( isset ( $tax_object->labels->singular_name ) ) {
                    $tax_label = $tax_object->labels->singular_name;
                } elseif ( isset( $tax_object->label ) ) {
                    $tax_label = $tax_object->label;
                    // Trim label prefix since WC 3.0
                    if ( 0 === strpos( $tax_label, 'Product ' ) ) {
                       $tax_label = substr( $tax_label, 8 );
                    }                
                }
    
                $out .= '<p class="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '">';
                $out .= '<span class="attribute-label">' . esc_html( $tax_label ) . ':  </span>';
                $tax_terms = array();
    
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $single_term = esc_html( $term->name );
                    // Insert extra code here if you want to show terms as links.
                    array_push( $tax_terms, $single_term );
                }
    
                $out .= '<span class="attribute-value">' . implode(', ', $tax_terms) . '</span></p>';
    
            } else {
                $value_string = implode( ', ', $attribute->get_options() );
                $out .= '<span class="' . sanitize_title($name) . ' ' . sanitize_title( $value_string ) . '">';
                $out .= '<p class="attribute-label">' . $name . ': </p></span>';
            }
        }
    
        $out .= '</ul>';
    
        echo $out;
    }
```

Then to transform text to an image for some attributes, I use the code below:

````
``` /**
* Insert JavaScript to replace WooCommerce product attributes text with images.
*/
function my_woocommerce_attributes_images(){
    ?>
    <script>(function() {
      var list, index, element, attValue, imgURL;
 
      list = document.getElementsByClassName("attributeA");
 
      for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
        element = list[index];
 
        attValue = element.getElementsByClassName("attribute-value")[0].innerText;
 
        switch (attValue.trim()) {
 
          case "valueA":
 
            imgURL = "/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/cigar.png";
 
            break;
 
          case "valueB":
 
            imgURL = "/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/fish.png";
 
            break;
 
        }
 
        element.innerHTML = '<span class="attribute-label">Atteibute A: </span><img src="' + imgURL + '" width="20" height="20" />';
      }
    })();</script>
    <?php
 
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'my_woocommerce_attributes_images'); ```
````

**But I have the following problems:**

1. Currently, only one `case` can be possible. If two ore more are true, it will not load any images. So we need a for each loop here and out put all true values => images. But all of my tryout was not sucessfull.
2. Currently we have to insert the code multiple times when we want to transform text to images from more than one attribute. I already tried to add a for each loop for `list = document.getElementsByClassName("attributeA");` in order taht we can have there something like `list = document.getElementsByClassName("attributeA", "attributeB", "attributeB");` But I'm not able to get this to work.
3. In order to make this more generic, also the `element.innerHTML = '<span class="attribute-label">Attribute A: </span><img src="' + imgURL + '" width="20" height="20" />';` should be display the generic current Attribute lable name. But yeah, here I not able to add this in a ore generic way.

Any suggestions are welcome to make it work.